# How to change values of html form elements with onchange event of select in JSP with or w/o javascript

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp

```js
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

        var userArray = '<%= userList%>';
        
        function setData()
        {
            for(var i=0;i<document.getElementById('userId').selectedIndex;i++);
            var selectedUser = userArray.get(i);
            
            if (document.updateUserForm.userId.selectedIndex > 0)
            {
                document.getElementById('userName').text = selectedUser.getUserName();
                document.getElementById('userPassword').text = selectedUser.getUserPassword();
                document.getElementById('userType').value = selectedUser.getUserType();
                document.getElementById('branchId').value = selectedUser.getBranchId();
            }
        }
    </script>
    <body>
```

```html
<%-- 
    Document   : UpdateUser
    Created on : Sep 27, 2015, 8:36:02 PM
    Author     : Pruthwiraj Ghadge <rayscareersolutions@yahoo.in>
--%>

<%@page import="java.util.Iterator"%>
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
<%@page import="in.rayscareersolutions.dao.User"%>
<%@page language="java" contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Update User Page</title>
    </head>
    <%
        User users[];
        List<User> userList;
        Iterator iter;
        int index = 0, uId;

        userList = (ArrayList<User>) request.getAttribute("userList");

        iter = userList.iterator();

        users = new User[userList.size()];

        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            users[index] = (User) iter.next();
            index++;
        }
    %>
    <h1>Update User</h1>

        <form id="updateUserForm" name="updateUserForm" action="UpdateUserServlet" method="post">
            <br><br>
            <label>User Id : </label>
            <select id="userId" name="cmbUserId" onchange="setData()">
                <%
                    int i;
                    for (i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
                        uId = users[i].getUserId();
                %>
                <option value='<%=uId%>'><%=uId%></option> 
                <%
                    }
                %>
            </select>
            <br><br>
            <label>User Name : </label>
            <input id="userName" type="text" name="txtUserName">
            <br><br>
            <label>User Password : </label>
            <input id="userPassword" type="password" name="txtUserPassword">
            <br><br>
            <label>User Type : </label>
            <select id="userType" name="cmbUserType">
                <option value="Cashier">
                    Cashier
                </option>
                <option value="BrManager">
                    Branch Manager
                </option>
                <option value="Admin">
                    Administrator
                </option>
                <option value="BankOfficer">
                    Bank Officer
                </option>
                <option value="TrManager">
                    Transaction Manager
                </option>
            </select>
            <br><br>
            <label>Branch Id : </label>
            <select id="branchId" name="cmbBranchId">
                <%
                    ArrayList<Integer> branchIdList;
                    int brId;

                    branchIdList = (ArrayList<Integer>) request.getAttribute("branchIdList");

                    iter = branchIdList.iterator();

                    while (iter.hasNext()) {
                        brId = Integer.parseInt(iter.next().toString());
                %>
                <option value="<%=brId%>"><%=brId%></option>
                <%
                    }
                %>
            </select>
            <br><br>
            <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="Update User">
            <input type="reset" name="btnReset" value="Reset">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am writing an application for basic banking process(web application with jsp-servlets).

[image: The User Update Form]

The above form is being used to update user data.
I want to display the user's current data on 'onchange' event of UserId combobox.

I tried using javascript but could not get it.
Please help.

[Form Part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNF44.png)

[Form Part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHIqB.png)

Comment: Post your attempt, *doesn't work` is not the right way to explain the problem ...

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself.

Comment: Wait I will add few more images for you to undestand

Comment: Do not simply add images, post actual code!

Comment: I am not able to add 2 more images as I do not have 10 reputations right now. I am new here

Comment: I have included the code of my JSP page with JavaScript code

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it with plain java script would involve creating an additional input (type=hidden) field and adding it to your form.

```
<form id="updateUserForm" method="post" >
....     
<input type="hidden" name="userVal" id="userVal">
...
</form>
```

For the onchange event , write the following java script function

```
function selectData(){
var userSelect=document.getElementById("userId");//combo box
var form=document.getElementById("updateUserForm");
for (var i = 0; i < userSelect.options.length; i++) {
    if (userSelect.options[i].selected == true) {
        var selValue=userSelect.options[i].value;           
        document.getElementById("userVal").value=selValue;//this will be sent to your servlet
        form.submit();
        break;  
    }
}
}
```

In your servlet (or your JSP if you don't have a servlet), fetch the data for your userVal (hidden input)

```
....

Integer userId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("userVal"));

//get user data from the database based on userId and store them in your   request object

....//Access DB here
request.setAttribute("userName", userName);//userName fetched from your DB
request.setAttribute("userPsw", userPsw);//userPsw fetched from your DB
```

Alternatively, you can use the setParameter method, since all your values are Strings and not Objects.

In your JSP, you can display your fetched user name by using

```
<input id="userName" type="text" value="${userName}" >
```

I hope this helps.